# What's a good way to remember the difference between a cardiogram and a cardiograph?

Tags: confusables

A cardiogram is a record of muscle activity, and a cardiograph is the machine that produces it -- I know and understand this difference. That said, every time I'm having to use one of these words (or recollect them), I confuse the two. Is there a good way to remember which is which?

Comment: It's consistent with other usage -- e.g., a _telegram_ is (was?) the message, a _telegraph_ was the device which transmitted it.

Comment: I'd appreciate if one can explain the downvotes. Just trying to improve my skills here -- didn't the answer to this question reveal an interesting aspect of the English language?

Comment: @WorldGov - I agree, it is hard to understand why people might downvote and even 'vote to close' without giving any reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really is tricky because there is no hard and fast rule.

Autographs do not make autograms; monographs do not make mongrams, and photographs do not make photograms.  In fact:

> A *cardio*-***gram*** is a record of muscle activity. A *cardio-**graph*** makes cardiograms.
>
> An *auto-**gram*** is a sentence that describes itself in the sense of providing an inventory of its own characters.  An *auto*-***graph*** is a signature.
>
> A *photo-**gram*** is a picture produced with photographic materials, such as light-sensitive paper, but without a camera.  A *photo-**graph*** is an image created by light falling on a photosensitive surface, usually photographic film or an electronic image sensor, such as a CCD.
>
> A *mono-**gram*** is a motif made by overlapping or combining two or more letters or other graphemes to form one symbol. A *mono-**graph*** is a specialist work of writing on a single subject or an aspect of a subject, often by a single author, and usually on a scholarly subject.

If it is only the 'cardio-' pairing that is important then ***I*** might remember by saying that the one with the ***m*** (i.e. cardiogram) is the one that is NOT the ***m***-achine.  But that's just the way my mind works!

Comment: How interesting! I'll add two more for fun: An *epigram* is a terse, sage, or witty and often paradoxical saying, while an *epigraph* is a quotation set at the beginning of a literary work or one of its divisions to suggest its theme. A *phonogram* is a character or symbol used to represent a word, syllable, or phoneme, while a *phonograph* is a an instrument for reproducing sounds by means of the vibration of a stylus or needle following a spiral groove on a revolving disc or cylinder. (Quoting merriram-webster.com.)

Comment: That poses an interesting question for semanticists: how did _graph_ and _gram_ grow to have these multiple meanings.